How to Fix IMUL and DIV Errors in Assembly Calculator Code?
I'm currently learning assembly language and trying to write a simple calculator program. The program is supposed to read two numbers and an operator (+, -, *, /) from stdin, perform the specified operation, and print the result. However, I'm encountering some issues with the IMUL and DIV instructions in my code. Here’s what I have so far
section .bss
    num1 resb 8         ; Buffer to store the first number (max 8 bytes)
    num2 resb 8         ; Buffer to store the second number (max 8 bytes)
    operator resb 1     ; Buffer to store the operator (1 byte)
    result resb 16      ; Buffer to store the result (max 16 bytes)

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Read the first number
    mov rax, 0          ; syscall number (sys_read)
    mov rdi, 0          ; file descriptor (stdin)
    mov rsi, num1       ; buffer to store input
    mov rdx, 8          ; number of bytes to read (max 8 bytes)
    syscall             ; call kernel

    ; Read the operator
    mov rax, 0          ; syscall number (sys_read)
    mov rdi, 0          ; file descriptor (stdin)
    mov rsi, operator   ; buffer to store input
    mov rdx, 1          ; number of bytes to read (1 byte)
    syscall             ; call kernel

    ; Read the second number
    mov rax, 0          ; syscall number (sys_read)
    mov rdi, 0          ; file descriptor (stdin)
    mov rsi, num2       ; buffer to store input
    mov rdx, 8          ; number of bytes to read (max 8 bytes)
    syscall             ; call kernel

    ; Convert first number from ASCII to integer
    movzx eax, byte [num1]
    sub eax, '0'

    ; Convert second number from ASCII to integer
    movzx ebx, byte [num2]
    sub ebx, '0'

    ; Perform the specified operation
    mov cl, byte [operator]
    cmp cl, '+'
    je add_operation
    cmp cl, '-'
    je sub_operation
    cmp cl, '*'
    je mul_operation
    cmp cl, '/'
    je div_operation

add_operation:
    add eax, ebx
    jmp output

sub_operation:
    sub eax, ebx
    jmp output

mul_operation:
    imul eax, ebx
    jmp output

div_operation:
    xor edx, edx
    div ebx
    jmp output

output:
    add eax, '0'
    mov [result], al
    mov [result+1], 0 ; null terminator for safety
    mov rax, 1          ; syscall number (sys_write)
    mov rdi, 1          ; file descriptor (stdout)
    mov rsi, result     ; buffer to store output
    mov rdx, 2          ; number of bytes to write (result + null terminator)
    syscall             ; call kernel

    ; Exit
    mov rax, 60         ; syscall number (sys_exit)
    xor rdi, rdi        ; exit code 0
    syscall             ; call kernel


When I run this code, I get the following errors:
main.asm:60: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
main.asm:71: error: operation size not specified

I am not sure how to fix these issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

mov [result+1], 0  should of course be mov byte [result+1], 0 What line is the other error on? I don't get that.

Looks like it's on imul eax, ebx.  That seems perfectly fine and I don't get an error either with NASM 2.16.01, using nasm -f elf64 -o foo.o foo.asm.  OP: please state the version of nasm you are using, and the exact command line options you used when running it.

Also make sure that this is actually the exact same code you are trying to assemble.  For instance, did you save the file in your editor before running the assembler?

OP: why do you say there is an error with DIV?  The error messages you posted don't mention that line.  Unless, again, the file you're assembling doesn't match the code you posted.

A couple of bugs that you're going to find after getting it to build: (1) think carefully about the lengths that you are passing to the read system call, and how the input would have to look in order for them to work.  Unless your input format is very specific and unusual, the code you have is probably not right.  (2) What happens if the operation is not any of + - * /?

What processor are you assuming?  The original IMUL only had a one-operand form (assuming EAX as source and EDX:EAX as destination) and a three-operand form.  The two-operand form came in with the 80386.

@TimRoberts: The entire program is 64-bit, and every x86-64 CPU certainly supports 2-operand IMUL.  If OP weren't using a 64-bit assembler mode, there'd be way more errors.

Bug (3): Writing out a null byte after your digit is not desirable, unless you have extremely unusual and specific requirements.  If the output is a terminal, you just won't see it.  If it's to a file, the null byte will mess up most kinds of text processing.  Null terminators only make sense internally to a program, when working with functions that specifically expect null-terminated strings, and write is not one of them.  This does not accomplish any kind of "safety" so your comment is misleading.

(4) Consider testing for divide-by-zero so your program can do something more graceful than simply crash, which is the normal behavior of the div instruction in that case.

@TimRoberts: 8086 only had a one-operand form of imul.  The immediate form was new in 186. https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insIMUL .  But even when targeting bits 16, NASM defaults to allowing any form of any instruction.  (Unlike TASM or something where you had to use a CPU model directive.)  And as Nate said, this is bits 64 where even PPro features like cmov are baseline.

Yes, I missed the 64-registers, as obvious as they are.  That still doesn't explain the issue here.
